# How to create a generic React.FC?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was wondering whether there is an easy way of creating a generic `React.FC`.

My use case is the following: I want to create a generic table component for a page I'm working on, and I'd really like to have generic support in order to have type safety on possible click callback etc.

I already tried out a few things. Here are the props I'd like to have, first of all:

```
type Props<T> = {
    entries: Array<T>;
}
```

So, here is my first attempt:

```
export const DataGridBody = <T extends any>(props: Props<T>) => {

    return (
        <>
            {props.entries}
        </>
    );
}
```

What's working well, is that implementers can just use e.g. `<DataGridBody<MyType> .... />`. What's bad, is that it's not a React.FC but a JSX.Element, which apparently leads to missing autocompletion of props etc.

Okay, I tried and read up a bit more and here is my second attempt:

```
export const createDataGridBody = <T extends any>(): React.FC<Props<T>> => {
    return (props: Props<T>) => {
        return (
            <>
                ...
            </>
        )
    }
}

const PreTypedBody = createDataGridBody<number>();

<PreTypedBody 
    entries={[0, 1]}/>
```

Awesome! This works! And it is a React.FC with autocompletion. However, it's fairly clunky to use.

So, to sum it up, I was wondering if there is a good approach which kind of combines both of these?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting in autocompletion with FC?

Comment: Your first example [seems to autocomplete props just fine](https://imgur.com/a/S5ymswY) for me in the typescript playground. There shouldn't be any real reason here to use the `React.FC`, so so long as you conform to the structure of a functional component.

Comment: @AlexWayne Huh, you're right. I must've messed up something. So what's the downside to not making it a React.FC then?

Comment: The only downside I can think is you have to declare the `children` property yourself. But that's pretty easy `interface Props<T> { entries: T[]; children: React.ReactNode }`

Comment: @AlexWayne You're right... I just checked again on https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet/blob/master/README.md#function-components, and even they say it's not a big deal if it's elided. Okay, then my question kind of solved itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems for me worth good to go.

> Just picked the return type pf the FC and prop types from React and added manually, as passing a generic reverse to FC is not quite possible.

```
import React, {ReactElement, PropsWithChildren} from 'react';

interface NameProps<T> { 
  entries: T[];
}

const Name = <T>(props: PropsWithChildren<NameProps<T>>):ReactElement<any, any> | null => {
  return (
      <>
         ...
      </>
  );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDez0wCiANkiEgHZZwAKUEYAzgOrAwAWAwu8MQCZRKAXzgAzeiDgByQQSkBuAFCLgVJFFHokcAHIpydBowA8AFQB8uOIrhxKMKMCSMAXHFMBtALpKhy5WgQFIzweuRwALxwZuYAFGD0TG6GTKwc3LwClMZhSCkmFuYAlC74GCRk9sYoFACe2DW1lgA+cBQArsTEkZY4NnCCMO1QFG2dxL5AA)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. As mentioned in the comments, I must've messed up something when testing my first version. Seems like SO is once again the perfect debug rubberduck :)